# The Correct Way to Wrap an Inherited Dependency Property

Tags: wpf, inheritance, dependency-properties

I have a custom control that derives from `ToggleButton` and I want to wrap a DP on the base class.
Do I need to do this...

```
public new bool IsEnabled
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsEnabledProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(IsEnabledProperty, value);
        if (value && IsChecked == null)
            IsChecked = false;
    }
}
```

or is this ok...

```
public new bool IsEnabled
{
    get { return base.IsEnabled; }
    set
    {
        base.IsEnabled = value;
        if (value && IsChecked == null)
            IsChecked = false;
    }
}
```

It seems to work the same both ways but I don't know if there are any hidden problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not call anything else than `GetValue` and `SetValue` in the CLR wrapper of a dependency property. The reason is explained in the [XAML Loading and Dependency Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613563(v=vs.110).aspx) article on MSDN.

Instead of adding a new CLR wrapper, you could call `AddOwner` on the base class dependency property field to register another `PropertyChangedCallback`:

```
public class MyToggleButton : ToggleButton
{
    static MyToggleButton()
    {
        IsEnabledProperty.AddOwner(typeof(MyToggleButton),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(IsEnabledPropertyChanged));
    }

    private static void IsEnabledPropertyChanged(
        DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var myToggleButton = (MyToggleButton)o;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue && !myToggleButton.IsChecked.HasValue)
        {
            myToggleButton.IsChecked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, makes sense, my extra logic is within the same element and only when the base DP changes so this is perfect.

Comment: One point of clarification: the type of the second argument of `AddOwner` is `PropertyMetadata`, how does `AddOwner` know which metadata is being provided when there are no specific overloads to tell it (from what I can find in the docs...)?

Comment: That's all explained in the [Remarks section here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597484(v=vs.110).aspx) (last paragraph).

Comment: Yes, I had read that but its not really helping. It says that the merge behaviour depends on the type being merged, which is fair enough, but there is no mention about how the different types are routed into the DO.  I guess the `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` object is providing dependency injection via it's `Merg` method, based on it's constructor overloads?

Comment: No idea how that works. However, PropertyChangedCallbacks "are combined", which means the original and the added callbacks are both called.

Comment: Yes, it's normal multicast delegate subscription: couldn't really be otherwise. OK, thanks: just thought I'd ask. I get constant headaches from trying to understand these mysterious property metadata functions, was just looking for some relief!

Comment: "multicast delegate subscription"? certainly not. And it doesn't matter at all how it's actually implemented. All you need to know is that it's "merged", e.g. default value is replaced, but changed callbacks are all called. If you really care about the implementation, there is the [.NET Framework Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/).

Comment: I need to know how it works so that I can figure why sometimes it doesn't work. For example: why `DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ContentToggle), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ButtonBase)));` does not change the default style for a custom control.

Comment: Is there a Style for `ButtonBase` in `Themes/Generic.xaml` in ContentToggle's assembly? I doubt that this problem has anything to do with the way OverrideMetadata works.

Comment: Yep, in Themes/Generic.xaml have `<Style TargetType="{x:Type ButtonBase}"><Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ControlTemplate}" /></Style>`. Works fine with `TargetType="{x:Type local:ContentButton}"` so everything else is ok. But you're probably right, I was advised that it's could be because `ButtonBase` is abstract. Anyway, I just  respectfully disagree: the more you understand, the smaller the space to search for problems. :)